# Can you change where a user spawns in on your island?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hypixel-skyblock

In Minecraft Hypixel Skyblock, users can visit someone's private island. When they do, they always spawn in a specific spot. Is there a way to change where they spawn? Or is this built in and unchangeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@geo's answer is correct. There are other commands that you can use to set the spawn (use them to set where you are standing):

```
/sethome
/setspawn
/setspawnlocation
/setguestspawn
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `/sethome` where you are standing

Comment: Does this actually work or are you suggesting to try?